# Broadcom NetXtreme BCM5762 Gigabit Ethernet disconnects after a while

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, broadcom, wired

I have a HP EliteDesk 705 G1 with Ubuntu 2020 and the ethernet connection disconnects after a few minutes using it.

I tried what [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049302/wired-ethernet-not-working-ubuntu-18-04) [other](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141557/broadcom-netxtreme-bcm5721-gigabit-ethernet-unable-to-connect-to-internet) questions suggest with no success.

Machine info:

```
HP EliteDesk 705 G1 SFF
Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5762 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 10)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a deep research my workaround is to add a kernel parameter.

Here's what I did:

1. Edit file on `/etc/default/grub`
2. Add the kernel parameter `iommu=pt`. Example: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash iommu=pt"`
3. Save file and apply changes with `sudo update-grub`
4. Reboot machine.

Hope helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

great workaround !  It works on my HP Elitedesk 705 G1 SFF Linux Mint 19.3 as well.

```
Network:   Device-1: Broadcom and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5762 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe 
       vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: tg3 v: 3.137 port: f100 bus ID: 03:00.0 
       chip ID: 14e4:1687 
       IF: eno1 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
```

You made my day, now I can finally get rid of my USB-Ethernet adaptor. !
Thanks !

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

Workaround worked for one hour or so, and suddenly stopped.  "No connection" - "Cable unplugged", which isn't the case.  Rebooting the workstation fixes this issue.  So small improvement (at least it works for a while), but no stable solution yet.